# align* in varwidth seems to ignore fleqn option

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, indentation, varwidth

I am using the `\documentclass` option `[fleqn]` (which I think is identical to `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`).  This seems to work fine, except when using an `align*` within the `varwidth` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- Problem does not occur with `align` (non-starred) environment.

### Code

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\MyContent}{%
Using align*:
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2
    \shortintertext{and}
    F &= ma
\end{align*}%
Using align
\begin{align}
    y = x + b
\end{align}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
Outside of \verb|varwidth|:

\MyContent

\noindent
Inside \verb|varwidth|:

\noindent
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \MyContent
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Followup Question: [Determine natural with of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394945/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the flag in the documented high level varwidth interface.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\MyContent}{%
Using align*:
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2
    \shortintertext{and}
    F &= ma
\end{align*}%
Using align
\begin{align}
    y = x + b
\end{align}%
}%

\makeatletter\let\@vwid@eqmodetrue\@vwid@eqmodefalse\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
Outside of \verb|varwidth|:

\MyContent

\noindent
Inside \verb|varwidth|:

\noindent vw\\
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \MyContent
\end{varwidth}

\noindent mp\\
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \MyContent
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Documented?" :-) `texdoc varwidth` opens up a one page document!!  I guess you have access to better documentation. :-).  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @PeterGrill note that this isn't really a "fix" that is you couldn't generally patch the package in this way. varwidth failed to understand `align*` so it decided this was a centred equation and re-centred it, the patch disables that test so it never decides that it was a centred equation. This wouldn't be correct if you were not using `fleqn` and needed that test.