# Determine natural width of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, indentation, varwidth

In an earlier question, [`align*` in `varwidth` seems to ignore `fleqn` option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394778/4301), it appeared as if `align*` was not being properly handled by the `varwidth` environment. A "fix" was provided which results in the correct visual display. But, measuring the result still reports that the box is of `\linewidth`.

Note that the two `varwidth`s report that same width of the box:

[image]

### Question:

- How do I measure the natural width of content that contains the use of `align*`?

### Notes:

- This is a followup to [align* in varwidth seems to ignore fleqn option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394778/4301).

### Related Questions:

- [Make box with minimum width (in math mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188343/4301).
- [Determine value of overfull amount([Determine value of overfull amount](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395197/4301)).
- [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}

\newcommand*{\MyContent}{%
    Using align*:
    \begin{align*}
        E &= mc^2
        \shortintertext{and}
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}%
}%

\newsavebox{\MySaveBox}
\newlength{\WidthOfSaveBox}

\newcommand{\ShowWidth}[1]{%
    \savebox{\MySaveBox}{#1}%
    \settowidth{\WidthOfSaveBox}{\usebox{\MySaveBox}}%
    \par\usebox{\MySaveBox}\par
    WidthOfSaveBox=\printlength{\WidthOfSaveBox}%
    \par\hrule
}%

\begin{document}

linewidth=\printlength{\linewidth}\hrule

\medskip
Inside of \verb|\parbox{0.5\linewidth}|:
\ShowWidth{%
    \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%
        \MyContent%
    }%
}

\medskip
Inside \verb|varwidth| (without patch):
\ShowWidth{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
        \MyContent
    \end{varwidth}%
}

\medskip% Works visually, but still uses full width
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394778/align-in-varwidth-seems-to-ignore-fleqn-option
\makeatletter\let\@vwid@eqmodetrue\@vwid@eqmodefalse\makeatother
Inside \verb|varwidth| (with patch):
\ShowWidth{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
        \MyContent
    \end{varwidth}%
}

\medskip%% This works fine.
Inside \verb|varwidth| with non-display content:
\ShowWidth{Some text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the width you are interested in include the `\intertext` or just the math?  Also, is supporting `\intertext` a required part of any solution?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, I need it to include the `\intertext` and do need `\intertext` support.

Comment: it is reported as that width because it is that width, rows of an alignment are full width boxes to allow page breaking if nothing else.

Comment: If the align has `\intertext` then it really is full width as that is a paragraph set with lines the current `\hsize` without that you could dump the column width data saved by the first `\@measuringtrue` pass of the alignment which will give you the max width of each column so you could in theory work something out, perhaps.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Can't the text in`\intertext` be measured using `\varwidth` and then use the maximum of that and the displaymath to deternine the actual "natural" width?

Comment: If you had unreasonable amounts of free time and were prepared to go on and modify the internals of every command that appeared inside varwidth to make them add new nested varwidth constructs then yes, but if you are just using varwidth as a black box that typesets its content naturally and then measures what it gets, then no.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK, how about without the `\intertext{}` then?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably of no use to you, because you want it specifically for `align*`.  However the `tabstackengine` package, which can build `align`-like entities in an `hbox`, keeps track of the individual cell contents, widths, heights and depths, which can be later recalled.

[Make sure you use it in conjunction with V1.5 of the `listofitems` package.]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\alignShortstack{E=&mc^2\\F=&ma}
\]
The logical size of the align structure is
   \TABcells{} rows/\TABcells{1} columns.\\
The width of column 1 is \TABwd{1}\\
The width of column 2 is \TABwd{2}\\
The height of row 1 is \TABht{1}\\
The height of row 2 is \TABht{2}\\
with an \Sstackgap{} gap between rows.\\
The tokens of cell 1,2 are \getTABcelltoks[1,2]``%
  \detokenize\expandafter{\the\TABcelltoks}''\\
The tokens of cell 2,2 are ``\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\TABcellRaw[2,2]}''\\
That cell's contents (in the prevailing TAB mode/style)\\
\mbox{}~~~can be recovered as ``\TABcell{2}{2}''\\
\fboxsep=0pt\relax
That cell, accounting for its presented row height \&\\
\mbox{}~~column width, may be recovered as \fbox{\TABcellBox{2}{2}}\\
In the case of cell 2,1, that would be \fbox{\TABcellBox{2}{1}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, the natural width of the overall align structure can be obtained as

```
\dimexpr\TABwd{1} + \TABwd{2}\relax
```