# Determine value of overfull amount

Tags: formatting, boxes, minipage, varwidth

If I set content into a box that is not wide enough (`0pt` in the MWE below), I get an overfull mesage displayed in the console. Can I obtain the maximum value reported in the messages

> Overfull \hbox (XXXXX too wide)

after typsetting the contents into a `\savebox`?

Below, I am manually setting

```
\setlength{\OverfullSize}{77.16191pt}
```

and am looking for a way to get the actual value reported as `XXXXX`.

[image]

### Notes:

- Requiring multiple passses is acceptable.
- Having a solution to this would let me solve my earlier question: [Determine natural width of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394945/4301).
- Somewhat related question: [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{pt}

\usepackage{varwidth}
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394778/align-in-varwidth-seems-to-ignore-fleqn-option
\makeatletter\let\@vwid@eqmodetrue\@vwid@eqmodefalse\makeatother


\newsavebox{\TempSavebox}
\newcommand*{\DetermineOverfullSize}[2]{%
    \savebox\TempSavebox{%
        \begin{varwidth}{0pt}%
            #2%
        \end{varwidth}%
     }%
     \setlength{\OverfullSize}{77.16191pt}% <-- How to determine the max overfull \hbox?
     \usebox{\TempSavebox}\par%
}

\newcommand*{\MyContentA}{%
\begin{align*}
    y &= mx + b \\
    F &=ma
\end{align*}%
}

\newcommand*{\MyContentB}{%
\begin{align*}
    y &= mx + b \\
    \shortintertext{and}
    F &=ma
\end{align*}%
}


\newlength{\OverfullSize}
\begin{document}
\DetermineOverfullSize{\OverfullSize}{\MyContentA}
\hrule
Above box is overfull by: \printlength{\OverfullSize},

\DetermineOverfullSize{\OverfullSize}{\MyContentB}
\hrule
Above box is overfull by: \printlength{\OverfullSize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: similar to your last question. In classic tex you can't take the box apart (as the mathon.mathoff nodes do not have `\unskip` equivalents so the only way "from the outside" is to parse the log file.  If you know it is an ams alignment and you change the code of align to record all the widths it sees in some global place then perhaps... So not necessarily impossible but not that easy. (luatex would be easier)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I can't easily get theactual  value, is it possible to at least detect if an `overfull \hbox` did or did not occurr? within a `\savebox{}`.

Comment: Short answer no. Longer answer tex is turing complete so if you are prepared to throw enough code at it, probably yes. (this question is I suspect harder than you think it should be:-)