# Automatically detect overrunning minipage

Tags: minipage, warnings

What is the best way to detect whether the content of a minipage runs over the right boundary of that minipage?

I do not want to detect it visually, but have an automatic check whether this happens.

Comment: there will always be an overfull box warning in the log file.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "automatic" check. From outside just look at the log, from inside TeX you'd better use Lua https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395197/determine-value-of-overfull-amount

Comment: @user202729 from outside. Can I distinguish this overfull box from other overfull boxes?

Comment: @JFabianMeier you have the source line number, so yes.